# Touch event for mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, touch

In a web application touch-version,
I'm converting  *mouse events*  to *touch events*.
mousedown=>touchstart,
mouseup=>touchend...

> I also want to convert *mouseover* event.
>
> Touch *mouseover* ? it is ansurd, the touchpad doesnt detect your finger in the air !
>
> Not really, if you swipe your finger over an element, e.g. And you want the element to get bigger... for example.

Is there a touch event for such a behaviour (mouseover for touch) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual mouse event by JQuery mobile
is quite welldone.
https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseover/

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) user interface library does not support the use of touch events in their widgets and interactions. This means that the slick UI you designed and tested in your desktop browser will fail on most, if not all, touch-enabled mobile devices, becuase jQuery UI listens to mouse events—mouseover, mousemove and mouseout—not touch events—touchstart, touchmove and touchend.
>
> That's where [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) comes in. Touch Punch works by using [simulated events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) to map [touch events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/) to their mouse event analogs. Simply include the script on your page and your touch events will be turned into their corresponding mouse events to which jQuery UI will respond as expected.

Visit the [website](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and read the documentation.

Comment: Actually, my cordova app gets well touchstart, touchend. touchmove is tricky cause - not like mousemove - it listens to the element where touchstart happens, not the document like touchmove. Source : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/?redirect_from_locale=fr

Answer (score -1):

You should try trigger('click') on on('mouseover',function(){});